# Angular Ng-Select only selects one option when two of the same are given

Tags: angular, html-select, angular-ngselect

I am relatively new to angular. I am currently working on my first project and got to know ng-select. Great modification but now I have a problem:

I have an array of objects as options from which are a few pre-selected. These objects all differ in at least one aspect which is the ID. The description can be the same but this should be rare.
When two of the pre-selected Objects have the same name then only one is selected. This only happens when bindLabel = "name" when bindLabel = "id" then both are selected and shown.

How can I fix this? Is there an option to bindLabel ="id" but show the "nam" or something like this? Thanks for the help.
Images are below.

[Code of ng-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euNMT.png)

[Picture of select with id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSqfH.png)

[Picture of select with name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOXYB.png)

[Model of Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cNK4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For everyone checking on this question. I couldn't exactly fix the problem.
However I created an extra attribute in my model that combines all the shown attributes. This reduces the chance that two objects have the exact same value and are not correctly shown.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a bindValue property which decides which part of the object is to be selected as value(on select).

You can read more about it [here](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/bindings)

If I understand correctly, You are trying to achieve
bindLabel= "id + name"

There are a few solutions to your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420271/angular-5-ng-select-how-to-add-two-values-to-bindlabel).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).